# R file not generating in Android lollipop, luna in 64bit ubuntu

Tags: android, aapt

I am using ubuntu-64 bit, eclipse luna-64 bit, jdk-7 64 bit, Adt 23.0.4, Sdk tools 24.0.1 Android sdk platform tool-21, Android build tool-21.1.2.
No error is showing up in any of my xml, yet, My R file is not generating.

Comment: Try restarting the eclipse and clean the project after that

Comment: @SuhailMehta did that too several times..

Comment: Check out your resource file names for invalid characters (i.e.: Upper Case characters).

Comment: R file is not generating even when I choose "create a new android project" to create a empty project from File menu.

Comment: @DerGolem all well..

Answer (score 0):

Aaahhh..!!
Finally, I downloaded the sdk again and all got fine.
There was some problem in my android-sdk. My eclipse, java and ubuntu version all was fine.